# Getting Oracle 12 C Installation Error File Not Found

Tags: oracle, installation, oracle12c

I have downloaded two zip files of Oracle 12 C.

I have extracted and trying installing it on `Windows 10` `64 Bit`.

winx64_12102_database_1of2
winx64_12102_database_2of2

Setup is available in folder one running the same from there.

Every time I am getting below error
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this Error is simply when you are unzipping the folders unzip at one common folder as i have done

You will find components folders as shown below

D:\softwares\12coracle\winx64_12102_database_1of2\database\Components

D:\softwares\12coracle\winx64_12102_database_2of2\database\stage\Components

Please try to read the log details as shown in screenshot above,its showing the path where installation log are being created. The location was C:\Program Files\Oracle\Inventory\logs \installActions2016-01-26_01-50-16AM.

After going through the logs i found that,In my case it was not able to find the files at below path during the installation

D:\softwares\12coracle\winx64_12102_database_1of2\database\stage\Components\oracle.rdbms\12.1.0.2.0\1\DataFiles
Because there was other unzipped part as shown below and it was unable to get the files at abovepath  Hence i copied all the file from below path to the above path location

D:\softwares\12coracle\winx64_12102_database_2of2\database\stage\Components\oracle.rdbms\12.1.0.2.0\1\DataFiles
I ran the whole installation again and folks it completed in overall 55 mins the overall installation with the plugable and container database configuration itself.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below steps:

1. Abort the current installer.
2. Navigate to second folder  **/database/stage/Components/** and copy all the files.
3. Paste all the files in first folder location **/database/stage/Components/**
4. Finally , run the **setup.exe** as administrator